# Finding the radius of a circle

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, circles

> Given a point A that outside a circle so that $AT$ is tangent to the
>   circle in point $T$
>
> And $AC$ is a secant to that circle in points $B,C$.
>
> From points $B,C$ we build heights to $AT$ in points $D,E$. (point $E$ is between points $D,T$)
>
> $BD=b$, $CE=c$, angle $TAC=\alpha$.
>
> What's the expression of radius $r$ in terms of $b,c,\alpha$?

I'm trying to find a nice solution maybe euclidean or trigonometric/vectors.

Comment: Welcome to math.SE! What did you already try to solve it? Besides, what do you *know* about it? Without knowing the tools you have at your disposal, it is impossible to explain anything.

Comment: thanks! i tried the basics like law of sine, cosine, similarity.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[image]

$AB=b\csc\alpha$, $~AC=c\csc\alpha$ $\Longrightarrow$ $AB\cdot AC=AT^{2}$, $~AT=\sqrt{bc}\csc\alpha$
$\angle BTA=\theta=\angle BCT$ $\Longrightarrow$ $2r=\dfrac{BT}{\sin\theta}=\dfrac{BT^{2}}{BD}=\dfrac{BD^{2}+DT^{2}}{BD}=\dfrac{b^{2}+(AT-AD)^{2}}{b}$
$=\dfrac{b^{2}+(\sqrt{bc}\csc\alpha-b\cot\alpha)^{2}}{b}$

$\therefore$ $r=\dfrac{b^{2}+(\sqrt{bc}\csc\alpha-b\cot\alpha)^{2}}{2b}$

Comment: if $E$ is located between somewhere of points $D$ and $T$ (the secant is higher) will it change the result? i just can't post a sketch..

Comment: $c~$ is used just only for $AT$'s length. so the result doesn't change.

Comment: i see, nice solution thanks

Comment: chole_shi you are nocturnal.am i right????????????

Comment: I'm in South-Korea near to China.